# Breeze js - how to handle 302 redirection in query response

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, breeze

How can I handle an error resulting from a Breeze query where the error is as a result of the XHR request getting a 302 redirection response.

This happens because my controller is protected by authentication and when the session expires the next request get redirected to the login page  - an HTTP 302 response is returned with a location header for the login page.

When I examine the error object returned by the promise the XHR object is not populated by with the 302 code or anything I can use to identify the error - I assume this is because strictly speaking 302 is not an error

How can I trap this using Breeze and redirect the browser to the login page

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what is actually being returned to the client, this is difficult to answer, but you can intercept the Breeze's ajax response processing by providing your own breeze ajax adapter and then process the raw Http response yourself before Breeze sees it. Something like:

```
var origAjaxCtor = breeze.config.getAdapter("ajax");
var newAjaxCtor = function () {
    this.name = "newAjax";
    this._origAjaxCtor = new origAjaxCtor();
}
newAjaxCtor.prototype = new oldAjaxCtor(); // to delegate all other methods
newAjaxCtor.prototype.ajax = function (settings) {
   settings.success = function((data, textStatus, XHR) {
      // interpret the results yourself; augmenting them if needed
      ... { your code here } ...
      // and then call the original success code
      settings.success(data, textStatus, XHR);

   });
   // perform the actual ajax call - this will call your custom success method from    above.
   this._origAjaxCtor.ajax(settings);
}
// register the new adapter
breeze.config.registerAdapter("ajax", newAjaxCtor);
// make this adapter the default
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("ajax", "newAjax", true);
```